# Spring Boot Actuator requires @EnableWebMvc but that turns off other features

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I got confused trying to integrate Actuator to a project using Spring Boot 1.5.11's static resource serving feature:

1. Spring Boot Actuator does not work without `@EnableWebMvc`, HTTP 406 is returned because the right Http media converter is not installed.
2. But if I add `@EnableWebMvc`, it turns off serving resources from the `static` folder and other Spring Boot features.

Is there a way to initialize Actuator without losing Boot features?

Comment: Spring Boot automatically adds `@EnableWebMvc` for you and with that the auto configuration. If you add it yourself spring boot skips all of that. The fact that something doesn't work probably means you are either messing around with the media converters/spring mvc config yourself already basically disabling the default  converters from being added. Add some configuration, code and the full stacktrace.

Comment: I don't register anything myself, but Spring Data Rest autoconfigures lots of MVC and Jackson stuff, so I suspect something goes wrong there. Unfortunately I'm under time pressure so collecting and anonymizing all my config is not an option right now. I worked it around by adding back autoconfigured stuff I need manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a [bug](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/12900) in Spring Boot 2.0, it seems it was there in Boot 1.5 as well. Workaround: setting `favorPathExtension` to `false` turns off buggy code in `ServletPathExtensionContentNegotiationStrategy` and Actuator endpoints start working.

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.favorPathExtension(false);
    }
}
```